# finding maximal ideal of the set of matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

problem: Given $X=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
m & n \\
n & m
\end{pmatrix}
\mid
m,n \in \Bbb Z
\right\}$, find all the maximal ideal of $X$.

This's my ideas:
let $f: X \to Z$x$Z$
, $\begin{pmatrix}
m & n \\
n & m
\end{pmatrix} \to (m,n) $. f is bijective function, so $X=Z$x$Z$

If $K$ is ideal of $X$, $K=I$x$J$, $I,J$ are ideal of $Z$.

$Z$ is domain ring, so $K=mZ$x$nZ$

$K$ is max ideal iff just one $I$ or $J$ is max ideal (Since product of two integral domains is not an integral domain).

so $K=A=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
pk & b \\
b & pk
\end{pmatrix}
\mid
k,b \in \Bbb Z
\right\}$ or $K=B\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & pk \\
pk & a
\end{pmatrix}
\mid
a,k \in \Bbb Z
\right\}$
($p$ is prime number).

but now $A,B$ are not ideal of $X$.

Where is my mistake? Help me sholve this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the operation defined on $\times$ in $K = I \times J$ ?

Comment: $I=\left\{
m \in \Bbb Z:
\begin{pmatrix}
m & n \\
n & m
\end{pmatrix}\in K
\right\}$

Comment: $J=\left\{
n \in \Bbb Z:
\begin{pmatrix}
m & n \\
n & m
\end{pmatrix}\in K
\right\}$

Comment: No, I mean what is the definition of the operation between the ideals ? I'm asking this because in the equation $K = I \times J$, the LHF is matrix, and the RHS is 2-tuples(probably), or something, but definitely not matrix.

Comment: @AnhThư You are mistaken when assume that $X=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ (actually this is an isomorphism) since you consider $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ as a ring with multiplication $(a_1,a_2)(b_1,b_2)=(a_1b_1,a_2b_2)$ (only in this case can decide that an ideal is of the form $I\times J$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

An ideal $I$ of a unitary commutative ring R is maximal iff $R / I$ is a field.

Comment: Thanks, i've known it.but I don't know how to find they